# ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanels Will Not Detect Other UpdatePanel Changes

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have two update panels on one web page.  They are both set to UpdateMode="Conditional". They are not nested. My problem is that when I want a control on UpdatePanelOne to update a control on UpdatePanelTwo the control on two will never be updated.  I don’t want to set the UpdateMode to always.  How can I get UpdatePanelTwo to reflect the changes that occur on UpdatePanelOne?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I'm not 100% that this is what you are looking for but using triggers may be the answer:

e.g.

in web form:

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
```

and in code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "YO";
}
```

Where clicking the Button1 in the first update panel triggers the update of the Text property of Label1 in the second update panel.